# AngularJS vs 2 vs 4 and Ionic 2vs3

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

Is there a benefit to converting/learning Angular 2 over Angular 4 when moving away from
AngularJS?

Is there a reason to not jump directly to Ionic 3 and Angular 4 from Ionic(1) and AngularJS(1)?

Comment: It is more prevalent question for many people when they start Angular  and confusing for many people who just follows tech.  The question have credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular4 is Angular2.

It was called in first releases Angular2, but cause of growing versions they called it just Angular.

Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

First sentence:

> Angular is the name for the Angular of today and tomorrow. AngularJS is the name for all v1.x versions of Angular.

Angular's weekly meeting notices: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rC5dz7AkCZP813daT_bccbS-20OLmXgBVi50CSKx148/pub#h.4fbeacydrf6u

> **Branding**
>
> - Last week blogged that we prefer 'Angular' for v2.x+ and 'AngularJS' for v1.x
> - We've made this change throughout everywhere we can find in docs, wiki, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's true that because Angular 2 was such a change that suddenly 2 and 4 are the same.

Comment: It's the same "product", but another version.. with breaking changes of course! There will follow Angular5, Angular6, Angular7, ..... They are using SemVer. Cause of this irritations they just called it Angular during January.. But most sides, like StackOverflow, use Angular2..